# Find the shortest whole repetitive substring (part 3)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

This is a new discussion from this post ([Find the shortest whole repetitive substring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/find-the-shortest-whole-repetitive-substring)) and since it is totally new code, I post as a new thread here.

The major initiative of posting a new thread is, RobAu has posted a smarter idea, and there is no implementation, and I implemented the ideas and has simple prove the ideas is correct. Post my code and simple prove here for advice.

**The problem**,

I'm working on a problem to find wholly repeated shortest substring of a given string, and if no match, return the whole original string.

**Input and output example**

```
catcatcat => cat
catcatcatdog=>catcatcatdog
aaaaaa = > a
```

**Major idea of the algorithm**,

Try to match the first shortest repetitive candidate as the first character of original string, if there is no match, treat the whole non-matched string as next candidate.

I have a simple prove why `if there is no match, treat the whole non-matched string as next candidate` is correct,

1. Let us say, previous candidate length is `N` and is not satisfied during current comparison, previous matched length is `N*k` (previous candidate matched for `k` times)
2. Suppose and there could be another satisfied candidate, whose length is `N+x` (`1<x<N`) and this candidate can match `p` times for previous matched string. Then,
   `N*k = (N+x)*p`, in other words `N*k/(N+x) = p`, since `N/(N+x)` is not integer, but `k` and `p` are both integer, it could not be satisfied.
   (At the same time, we know if `N` length string does not match, `2N`, `3N`, etc. does not match, it is why I choose `x` as as value between `1` and `N` in previous analysis.)
3. So, we have to treat the whole mis-matched string as next whole repetitive string candidate.

**My code**

```
def check_shortest(original_string):
    current_candidate = original_string[0]
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(original_string)):
        if original_string[i] == current_candidate[j]:
            j+=1
            if j == len(current_candidate):
                j = 0
        else:
            current_candidate= original_string[:i+1]

    return current_candidate if j == 0 else original_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print check_shortest('catcatcat') #cat
    print check_shortest('catcatcatdog') #catcatcatdog
    print check_shortest('aaaaaa') #a
    print check_shortest('aba')  # aba
```

Comment: (For python 2, avoid `range` habitually.) There are bugs when the string is short ('aba', check `j` on return) or the pattern ends as it starts ('abaaba') - not confident that this can be reconciled (aⁿba²ⁿabaⁿa - I _think_ a repeated character at the start is _the_ special case. Keep the length of that, new `candidate` shorter by that (and `j` reset accordingly) _if_ `j` no larger at mismatch?)(failed proving [RobAu's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144465/93149)).

Comment: @greybeard, nice catch, fixed the bug for `aba` case. What do you mean `a^(n)ba^(2n)aba^(n)a`? What the `n` means here? Could you show a specific example?

Comment: a² = aa, a³ = aaa, …: the `ⁿ` in `(expression)ⁿ` means _repeat expression n times_.

Comment: (Lin Ma's edit to revision 2 didn't touch anything addressed in [Dair's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144981/93149).)

Comment: @greybeard good find. let me think a bit on this

Comment: @greybeard, could you show an example where RobAu's algorithm not working?

Comment: @RobAu, I think your algorithm works even if begin character is repetitive, is there a counter example?

Comment: Did you try `'abaaba'`? Result? (Did you try `""`?)

Comment: @greybeard, nice catch, yes, it does not work. But what is wrong with the logic? Is it because when there is a mis-match, we start with the whole mis-match prefix is too aggressive -- and we should choose something in the middle? I debugged my posted code with `abaaba`, when the middle `aa` does not match candidate `ab`, it tries `abaa` other than trying `aba`?

Comment: Yes, the core problem is that the "inspected prefix" of `original` _may_ be too optimistic (long) as a candidate. Going back to extend the candidate by char would ruin performance. Problematic are strings with at least three repetitions of the same pattern, at the ends: at least one as head and tail, at least one more at either end. For single repeated character, the code in my answer _should_ handle that: determine `prefix` and don't grow candidate beyond safe grounds.

Comment: @RobAu, any ideas to fix the issue pointed by greybeard?

Answer (score 1):

You currently write:

```
for i in range(len(original_string)):
```

Consider using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, char in enumerate(original_string):
    if char == current_candidate[j]:
```

`enumerate` allows you to reference the current object in a nice manner, while also giving you the index that the item belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Dair for the advice, for the correctness of the algorithm (I find the right shorest repetitive sub-string for the whole string), do you think it is correct?

Comment: @LinMa: I'm not sure at the moment, I posted this answer on the assumption that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: @greybeard: You don't need it, but is common not to index variables explicitly unless you have to in Python. Also, `i` can still be used.

Comment: Thanks Dair, you cannot assume my code is correct... I tested with my best trial but it could have bugs not producing the right results. Appreciate if you could have any comments on my original posted questions. :)

Comment: @LinMa If your code is broken, it would be off-topic here...

Comment: (@Graipher If the code _didn't appear to work_ when posted, it would have been off-topic. I found the algorithm a bitch to reason about, even to test.)

Answer (score 1):

- Use documentation strings
- comment
- use telling, but succinct names
- try to keep things simple
- (test "first": When putting considerable effort into
  implementing a procedure, have a test procedure in place to sustain confidence that it *does* solve the problem)

**NOT quite successful** attempt to fix RobAu/Lin Ma's approach, and no longer simple:

```
# Find "period" of a string:
# prefixes, grown as needed and warranted become candidates
def shortestCover(original):
    """return the shortest substring of the argument
    that equals it when repeated an integral number of times.
    BROKEN(incomplete): fails for 'ababccabababccabababccab'
     (repetitions of more than just one char
      at start _and_ end at special positions)
    """
    print "shortestCover BROKEN: fails for 'ababccabababccabababccab'"
 # length of prefix of original that might cover it if repeated
    candidate = i = 1
    oLen = len(original) # define halfLen?
 #  print original, oLen
    prefix = 0
    while (i < oLen):
    #  print i, candidate, prefix
    # no need for modulus:
    # the immediately preceding occurrence of
    #  the candidate pattern is as good as the first
        if original[i] == original[i - candidate]:
            i += 1
        else:
            if oLen // 2 < i: return original
        # part or all of prefix has unsuccessfully been assumed
        #  to be the start of the next occurrence:
        # candidate may need to be as far back from i as prefix,
        #  but must grow
        # (without re-scanning that part,
        #  this does _not_ raise WC run-time to O(n^3/2) )
            if (i <= candidate+prefix):
                candidate = max(candidate, i-prefix)+1
            # comparisons would be redundant upto&including i
                while (0 != oLen % candidate
                       and candidate <= i):
                    candidate += 1
            else:
                candidate = i + 1
        # if prefix isn't set yet,
        #  original starts with i occurrences of its 1st char
            if prefix == 0:
                prefix = i
        # allow divisors of original length as candidates, only
            while (0 != oLen % candidate):
                candidate += 1
                if oLen // 2 < candidate: return original
        # this may skip characters that never get nor need to be
        #  "on the right side of a comparison for equality"
            i = candidate if i < candidate else i+1;

    return original[:candidate]

import re
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for o in (#'',
              'abababab', 'aaaaaa', # not a prime length
              'ababa', 'abaaba', 'abaaaba',
              'aabaaba', 'aabaaaba', 'aabaaaaba',
              'aaaaccaaaaaaccaaaaaaccaa',
              'ababbbabababbbabababbbab',
              'ababbbababbbababbbababbb',
              'ababccabababccabababccab'):
        print re.match(r'^(.+?)\1*$', o).group(1)
        print shortestCover(o)
```

Comment: Hi greybeard, tried your code works and could you explain what is the logical meaning of `candidate = i-prefix` and logical meaning of `prefix` itself?

Comment: Thanks greybeard, I will study and debug more, would you mind to add 2-3 sentence of your algorithm in brief? It helps others (e.g. for Mr. RobAu. :)) to read better.

Comment: Find an issue in your code (not a bug, but a bit weird), you assign `prefix = i` only once, and `prefix` is always 1, is that what you desired?

Comment: Delete done. :))

Comment: Hi greybeard, have a chance to study your code logic in more details, your logic works in this way (please correct me if I am not correct understanding), if there is a mis-match at position `i`, you will set new candidate to be `original_string[0:i]`, **but** you never compare if set candidate to be `original_string[0:i]` works for current position `i` or not (in next iteration, you will increase `i`, and do you need to compare if `original_string[0:i]` is good for `i`?).  In RobAu's algorithm, if there is a mis-match at position `i`, he will set new  candidate to be `original_string[0:i+1]`

Comment: (cont'd) Your algorithm works for case `abaaba`, since when mis-match at `a` at position `3`, you treat candidate as `aba`, but RobAu's algorithm treat candidate as `abaa`, so you can find the right shortest sub-string `aba` next time, but RobAu's algorithm cannot. But I am a bit doubt if you algorithm has other issues, since when there is a mis-match at position `i` as I said, you just set candidate to be `original_string[0:i]`, but you never check if the candidate `original_string[0:i]` works at position `i` or not.

Comment: Hi greybeard, if you could advise on my above question, it will be great. :)

Comment: There has been an error in the first revision of the code in this answer in exactly the position you found dubious (and probably more). I couldn't decide whether the problem was not to (re-)check (that was by design - (a non-constant amount of) re-checking would preclude O(n)), or overlooking that increasing candidate might be skipped _if_ `i`/candidate was a divisor of `oLen` to begin with. I postponed explicitly answering your question 'til Godot appeared.